# The opposite of hyperbole

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, hyperbole

Is there a word that reflects the opposite of hyperbole (since "hypobole" is sadly not a real word)?

Comment: "**If your question is simple and can probably be easily answered by looking it up, then you may find common online internet resources to be of some help.** View our list of community recommended resources to find some that may be of help to you...Of course, if your question isn't adequately answered by these resources, feel free to ask here on English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. **Be sure to mention the research you've done** and what you're still hoping to learn."  https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks, Clare! Already did that and couldn't get a good answer.

Comment: also, checkout 'litotes'

Comment: I dont see where you "Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn."

Comment: Given that the [inverse of a hyperbola](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpkI2BNHjNQ) is also a hyperbola, it would seem to follow that the opposite of _hyperbole_ is also _hyperbole_.

Comment: The opposite of hyperbole is understatement.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest:

> [**understated** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/understated)
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Presented or expressed in a subtle and effective way.
>
> *‘It has that rare and refreshing eloquence of the understated.’*
>
> *‘Subtlety is the foremost element in this suavely written and understated novel.’*
>
> *‘His understated comedy, often just a subtle facial expression, was deeply funny to millions.’*

as a noun you can say "understatement"

> [**understatement** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/understatement)
>   NOUN
>
> The presentation of something as being smaller or less good or important than it really is.
>
> ‘a master of English understatement’

Comment: Understatement works then

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the style would match, but 'Spin' might be appropriate, as in 'using understatement and refocus to minimize the importance of something critical or disastrous'.